# ListViewItem not Selecting on Button Click 

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, selection

I have a ListView in which the ListView Items have button and textblock....

Senario :

I am able to click the button with out selecting the ListView Item i.e is the selection the last Item and then if i try to click the button of the first item the first time is not selected (In DataGrid it does select).

I Cannot use DataGrid as i am using CustomView in ListView.

If you need my code for reference of the problem i'll post it..

Any help in this regard would be great

```
My ListView :  

  <ListView Name="lv"
              Grid.Row="1"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              TextSearch.TextPath="{Binding Path=Person.Name}"
              View="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                             ElementName=viewComboBox}" />
```

My DataTemplates for CustomViews :

```
 <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type CustomView:PlainView},
                                    ResourceId=ImageView}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value=".5" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Name="bd"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <WrapPanel KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" 
                                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                                   MinWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).MinWidth,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                     AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                   IsItemsHost="True"
                                   ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth,
                                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Orientation="Vertical"
                                   Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type CustomView:PlainView},
                                    ResourceId=ImageViewItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="centralTile">
    <StackPanel Width="80" Height="40" KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="tempabc" Command="{Binding Path=Launch}" KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="True" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"></TextBlock>
            </Button>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Water lilies.jpg"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="13"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<CustomView:PlainView x:Key="plainView"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=centralTile}"
                              ItemWidth="100" />  
<GridView x:Key="myGridView">
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Please share a good code snippet that demonstrates your implementation/problem.

Comment: @mzabsky thanks for the gr8, but when you're editing don't forget to give the title some love, too.

Comment: @Avada Kedavra I posted the code. Is viewModel required ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most things, there are a number of ways to do this.  Here's one I just threw together in a minute...

Given the following model:

```cs
public sealed class ItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to display a collection of them to the user and select one via a button.  This means I need three things in my ViewModel:

1. A collection of ItemModels
2. A "SelectedItem" property to hold the currently selected instance
3. An ICommand implementation to bind to the buttons in the View

I create my ViewModel and add these items to it.  Please note, I prefer making my ViewModels extend DependencyObject rather than mess with INPC.

```cs
public sealed class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    // 1. A collection of ItemModels
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> ItemModels { get; private set; }
    // 2. A "SelectedItem" property to hold the currently selected instance
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(ItemModel),
            typeof(ViewModel),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public ItemModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (ItemModel)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
    // 3. An ICommand implementation to bind to the buttons in the View
    public Command SelectItem { get; private set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ItemModels = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        ItemModels.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "One" });
        ItemModels.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "Two" });
        ItemModels.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "Three" });
        SelectItem = new Command 
        { 
            ExecuteAction = x => SelectedItem = x as ItemModel 
        };
    }
}
```

Lastly, I slap together my UI with a rudimentary ListView.

```
<Window
    x:Class="q_7635202.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="WindowRoot">
    <ListView
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemModels}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                    Header="Name" /> 
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                Content="Select"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectItem,
                                                  ElementName=WindowRoot}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Its all pretty straight forward.  I'm leaving out the ICommand implementation as it is trivial.

Comment: It means in the ICommand Implemention ill will set the "SelectedItem" Property by the CommandParameter Object. Also you told You use DependencyObject insted of INPC is there ne advantage using  of that in MVVM

Comment: Opps you already did that in the Command initializer... my Bad

Comment: @adcool2007: DPs are the fastest binding in WPF, and I find them much easier to deal with than INPC.  Its a personal thing.